# Getting “Could not find part of the path”error

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, directory

I am using the FileUploader control in my web application. I'd like to upload the file in a specified folder. As the specific folder does not exist yet, I have to create the path it in my codes.

```
string folder = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

string path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/" + folder;
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
string server_path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/myfiles/";

FileUpload1.SaveAs(server_path + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: If you're sure the paths are the same, why do you have `path` and `server_path` variables?  Clearly they are different which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Even when I change it

Comment: The same error still appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetFileNameWithoutExtension gives you the file name, not the folder name. Then, if you have file `../../letter.txt`, it gives you `letter` and this is used to create directory.